# should i use empty() php function

Tags: php

which is better?

```
if (!empty($val)) { // do something }
```

and

```
if ($val) { // do something }
```

when i test it with PHP 5, all cases produce the same results. what about PHP 4, or have any idea which way is better?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should use the [`empty()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) construct when you are not sure if the variable even exists. If the variable is expected to be set, use `if ($var)` instead.

`empty()` is the equivalent of `!isset($var) || $var == false`. It [returns](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php#refsect1-function.empty-returnvalues) true if the variable is:

- `""` (an empty string)
- `0` (0 as an integer)
- `0.0` (0 as a float)
- `"0"` (0 as a string)
- `NULL`
- `FALSE`
- `array()` (an empty array)
- `var $var;` (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)

Comment: Really? I didn't think it worked that way. I have always had to run isset() before running empty(). But I just tried it out and it seems to be working great in PHP 5.3. Well you learn something new every day. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Read the  [manual](http://php.net/empty):

> empty() is the opposite of (boolean) var, except that no warning is
>   generated when the variable is not set.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to check this [article](https://www.beberlei.de/post/when_to_use_empty_in_php_i_say_never). It clarifies why the `empty` function can cause errors and is not very good practice for best results code.