# MySQL storing boolean - 1, 0 , or NULL

Tags: php, mysql, boolean

So I've generally stored Boolean values in MyIASM MySQL DBs using `TinytInt(1)`.  In a site I'm currently working on, I need to be able to store `1, 0 or NULL`.  This field is being populated from a radio button in a PHP form.

When I choose 'Yes' in the form (with a value of 1), this gets stored accurately.  When I choose 'No' however (with a value of 0), it gets stored as NULL.

I want to reserve NULL for if the user chooses neither 'Yes' or 'No'.

Any idea why the 'No' (0) values aren't storing as expected?

EDIT:

Here's the basic HTML:

```
Yes <input type='radio' name='video_transfer_dvd_question' value='1' /> 
No <input type='radio' name='video_transfer_dvd_question' value='0' />
```

Comment: Show the html for the radio buttons, and how you handle them in PHP once the form's submitted. Without any actual code, we can't help you.

Comment: Seems an issue of your code and no a MySql issue. Post your code please

Comment: I believe you're both right.  I printed the query MYSQL is using, and whenever I select 'No', it has  'video_transfer_dvd_question' set to NULL, instead of 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, both `''` and `0` are [considered `FALSE` in a boolean context](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php), so if you try to test `'' == 0` you'll find the result is `TRUE`. And [`empty()` only checks whether the argument is boolean `FALSE`](https://www.php.net/empty), so it doesn't truly distinguish between an empty `$_POST` and a `$_POST` which contains a value that happens to evaluate as `FALSE`. My suggestion would be to change the values of your radio buttons so than they never evaluate as boolean `FALSE`, e.g.:

```
Yes <input type='radio' name='video_transfer_dvd_question' value='yes' /> 
No <input type='radio' name='video_transfer_dvd_question' value='no' />
```

This keeps things more explicit when you test the response and choose a value to send to MySQL:

```
if (empty($_POST['button'])) {
    $value = NULL;
} elseif ($_POST['button'] == 'no') {
    $value = 0;
} elseif ($_POST['button'] == 'yes') {
    $value = 1;
}
```

You could also use `!$_POST['button']` in place of `empty($_POST['button'])`, but [that would generate a warning if `$_POST['button']` is not set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7260323/2359271), which you would probably rather not happen.

You could also change that last `elseif` block to a simple `else`, if you have no reason to expect that the possible responses to this radio button will ever change and don't care about being explicit.

Answer (score 0):

As the other people have commented its 99% an issue with your code...what you will need is something like...

```
if ($_POST["radiobutton"]) { $insertValue = 1; } else { $insertValue = 0; }

or

$insertValue = ($_POST["radiobutton"]) ? 1 : 0;
```

The reason is an empty radio button is an empty $POST var value which gets interpreted as NULL in mysql.

Comment: Right, but this isnt what I want.  I basically have 3 options.  Yes (1), No (0), or the user leaves it blank (Null).  Right now, when i submit a '0' it gets interpreted as NULL