# PHP checking a variable with empty() or truthy

Tags: php

Can anyone tell me the different between checking if a variable has value using the empty() function or "truthy" in an if statement? As far as I can tell they achieve the same thing?.. I am writing a function for Wordress that loops through the taxonomies and both work but I am not sure which is best.

```
   $taxonomies = get_taxonomies($args, $output, $operator);

      if (!empty($taxonomies)) {

      ...code here

    }
```

or

```
$taxonomies = get_taxonomies($args, $output, $operator);

  if ($taxonomies) {

...code here

}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: Second example will throw error if no variable named `$taxonomies` exists [should i use empty() php function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260323/should-i-use-empty-php-function)

Comment: it is not related to wordpress, this is a general php question, plenty of answers available sir.